# php image base64 encoding not working

Tags: php, image, base64

I hit an issue at my job where the base64 encoding did not work when I was using a full url. However I managed to make it work with relative path.

Here's the code only working with relative path :

```
$type = pathinfo($this->logo_path);
$data = file_get_contents($this->logo_path);
echo "data:image/" . $type . ";base64," . base64_encode($data);
```

when **$this->logo_path** === "http://domain-name/assets/img/logo.png", **$data** === NULL

Is there anyone here with an explanation? I need to convert the image to put a page in a pdf file. I was able to work around my problem with a boolean variable determining whether I need a base64 convertion or not, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem to be with base64, but rather with file_get_contents. Try changing the logo path to 'https://google.com' or any other website, then var_dump() the $data variable. If it works, your problem is with the URL itself. Maybe it needs to be url-encoded?

Comment: you probably are right about the url being wrong, but I just tried to encode it and decode it and it does not work.

it did work with the url of the google logo

Comment: And I also checked the resulting URL directly in my browser and it can find and show the image.

Comment: what does var_dump(file_get_contents('https://google.com')); show?

Comment: erm... NULL... wth

Comment: could it be that I'm not using the good function?

Comment: It seems your ```allow_url_fopen``` directive is set to false. Check ```phpinfo()``` and look for allow_url_fopen, if it's false and you can't change it, try using curl instead.

If it's correct I'll write up an answer real quick with some curl examples.

Comment: both are "on"

And what do you mean by "using curls"

Comment: oh my, I just got what you meant by "using cURL" hahaha I feel dumb. Anyways, I could work around the situation with my conditional convertion. and I can't test it anymore since the site is done.